# Trying to find average between the numbers of 2 different arrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to find out what's the average between the numbers of 2 different arrays. Well, actually I made it, the thing is, I'm making a verification, to make sure both arrays have the same length. Therefore when I commit the mistake (on purpose) of defining the length of one of them differentely, it shows the error message, and goes back to defining the array length, but when I make the calculous for the average, it returns it wrong, for some reason. Literally, everything works well, except when the function compararValores() is called.

Save me, please.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MediaVetores {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int vec1 [];
        int vec2 [];
        vec1 = lerVetor1();
        vec2 = lerVetor2();
        mediaVetores(vec1, vec2);
    }

    static int lerInteiro(String pergunta){
        System.out.println(pergunta);
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        return ler.nextInt();
    }

    static int [] lerVetor1(){
        int tamVetor = lerInteiro("Quantos valores quer inserir no 1º vetor?: ");
        int vec1 [] = new int [tamVetor];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamVetor; i++){
            vec1 [i] = lerInteiro("Insira o valor do " + (i+1) + "º número do vetor: ");
        }
        return vec1;
    }

    static int [] lerVetor2(){
        int tamVetor = lerInteiro("Quantos valores quer inserir no 2º vetor?: ");
        int vec2 [] = new int [tamVetor];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamVetor; i++){
            vec2 [i] = lerInteiro("Insira o valor do " + (i+1) + "º número do vetor: ");
        }
        return vec2;
    }

    static void mediaVetores(int vec1 [],int vec2 [] ){
        int n1 = 0;
        int c1 = 0;
        int n2 = 0;
        int c2 = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int soma = 0;
        double media = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vec1.length; i++){
            n1 = n1 + vec1[i];
            c1 ++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < vec2.length; j++){
            n2 = n2 + vec2[j];
            c2 ++;
        }
        soma = n1 + n2;
        System.out.println(soma);
        total = c1 + c2;
        System.out.println(total);
        compararVetores(vec1, vec2);
        media = (double) soma / (double) total;

        System.out.println("A média dos valores inseridos nos vetores é de " + media);

    }

   static void compararVetores (int a[], int b[]){
        if (a.length != b.length){
            System.out.println("Os vetores devem ter o mesmo número de valores! Volte a introduzir novos tamanhos de vetores.");
            lerVetor1();
            lerVetor2();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tangential: a vector is a specific thing in Java; these are arrays. It’s not clear what issue you’re having, but `compararVetores` ignores the returned arrays, unlike `main`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, yes arrays' you're tottaly right. how do I edit my post? And what do you mean by ignores the returned arrays?

Comment: Click on the "Edit" button above the comment section on your question. For `compararVetores`, you call `lerVetor1` and `lerVetor2` but do nothing with their result. You should avoid remaking `Scanner` every time for `System.in`: Make it once in `#main` and set it to a `private static` field. Since `#lerVetor1` and `#lerVetor2` don't actually update anything outside their own method, you might also benefit from keeping a non-static class to maintain your arrays. From there those `#ler` methods can update the class they're in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to simplify your code:

- Use only one instance of `Scanner`
- Use one method to create both arrays
- Avoid unused variables while calculating median

And then you do not need the `compararVetores()` method. In case it's mandatory to have both arrays with the same length, you should ask use once for an array size, and then ask to enter elements of each arrays eparately.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many values do you want to insert vector?: ");
    int total = scan.nextInt();

    int[] arr1 = createArray(scan, 1, total);
    int[] arr2 = createArray(scan, 2, total);

    mediaVectors(arr1, arr2);
}

private static int[] createArray(Scanner scan, int no, int total) {
    System.out.format("Enter total %d values of vector %d (space or enter are separators): ", total, no);

    int[] arr = new int[total];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();

    return arr;
}

private static void mediaVectors(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int total = arr1.length + arr2.length;
    int sum = Arrays.stream(arr1).sum() + Arrays.stream(arr2).sum();
    double media = (double) sum / (double) total;

    System.out.println("Sum of values: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Total values: " + total);
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "The average of the values entered in the vectors: %.2f", media);
}
```

**Output:**

```
How many values do you want to insert vector?: 4
Enter total 4 values of vector 1 (space or enter are separators): 1 2 3 4
Enter total 4 values of vector 2 (space or enter are separators): 5 6 7 8
Sum: 36
Total: 8
The average of the values entered in the vectors: 4.50
```

Answer (score 0):

: I'm sorry I'm kinda new to stack and programming in general, so this might not be as accurate as I think it is, plus I don't know very well how this forum works yet. Thanks alot for the help tho.
[image: This is what happens when I run it properly]

[image: And here it is after the verification for some reason]

Comment: If you are writing an answer please explain the answer. This looks like a comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).